# PYQt: multiple threads are running sequentially

Tags: python, multithreading, qt

I am trying to use Qt threads in my pyqt application, to avoid the UI running slow or hanging up while doing long process, however, after a lot of trials, I managed to run the code with no errors, but still I am not seeing any changes, other than the UI is running exactly the same....
I tried to simplify the code, and the following sample is basically what I am trying to do but with much further details included and GUI loaded (which is now frozen as long as I am not using  QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()). I am trying to invoke the same method multiple times, and each time a thread is expected to be running, and thus not hanging the UI.

```
import sys, traceback
import os
import subprocess
import time
import psutil
import signal
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui

class ProcessController (QtCore.QObject):
        processCmdDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

        @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
        def execCmd(self, cmd):
                print "started execution of execCmd" + cmd
                for  i in range(10000000000):
                        #any command process
                        pass
                self.processCmdDone.emit()
                print "ended execution of cmd " + cmd

class Build (QtCore.QObject):
        def starting (self,cmd):
                process_inst = ProcessController()
                thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
                process_inst.moveToThread(thread)
                process_inst.processCmdDone.connect(thread.quit)
                thread.started.connect(self.printstarted)                      
                thread.started.connect(lambda: process_inst.execCmd(cmd))
                thread.finished.connect(self.printdone)
                thread.start()

        def printdone(self):
                print "thread done"

        def printstarted(self):
                print "thread started"

if __name__=="__main__":
        app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
        build_inst = Build()
        build_inst.starting("cmd1")
        build_inst.starting("cmd2")
        build_inst.starting("cmd3")
        app.exec_()
```

the output indicates that no command starts execution until the previous command did finish, the empty for loop is intended to give some sort of delay during the execCmd:

```
thread started
started execution of execCmd cmd1
ended execution of cmd cmd1
thread started
thread started
started execution of execCmd cmd2
ended execution of cmd cmd2
started execution of execCmd cmd3
ended execution of cmd cmd3
thread done
thread done
thread done
```

I read somewhere that the python interpreter may not allow threading, but how can I determine if this is the case or the problem with my coding? I do appreciate your help.